# jsp content depending on a bool variable value

Tags: jsp

Is it possible that some content of the .jsp page(say form) is displayed only if a bool variable's value of this jsp page is true?

Thanks for considering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scriptlets
for example

```
<%

if (condition)
{

%>

your code

<%
}

else

{

%>

your code
<%
}
%>
```

Scriptlets are used for writing java codes..
If you want to get the the value of a variable use

```
<%=var %>
```

for example

```
<% if(id==1)
{
%>

  <tr>
    <td class="BodyStyle"><h5 align="left"><%=TokenNo%></h5></td>
    <td class="BodyStyle"><h5 align="left"><%=Time%></h5></td>
    <td class="BodyStyle"><h5 align="left">Booked</h5></td>
   </td>
   </tr>
  <%
  }
else
{
  %>
   <tr>
    <td class="BodyStyle"><h5 align="left"><%=TokenNo%></h5></td>
    <td class="BodyStyle"><h5 align="left"><%=Time%></h5></td>
    <td class="BodyStyle"><h5 align="left">Available</h5></td>
     </tr>
  <%    
    }
  %>
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought that this code would be printed on a page anywat but it is not)

Answer (score 2):

Use `<c:if>` from JSTL tag library.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
...

<c:if test="${myBooleanVariable}">
    <form>
    ...
    </form>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
<%
if (your_BoolVar){
%>
```

*Code your form hier*

```
<%
}
%>
```